# Existence of continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ that "respects norms"

Tags: general-topology, equivariant-maps

Is there a continuous map from $\pi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ that is $(\sim_n, \sim_{n-1})$-invariant where $\sim_n$ is the equivalence relation of equality up to orthogonal transformation, i.e. for each $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $\|a\| = \|b\|$ implies that $\|\pi(a)\| = \|\pi(b)\|$?

I don't have a lot of background in topology or geometry so maybe the answer can be found by applying some basic result.

I am working on a dimension reduction idea and was considering the map $\pi: \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, defined everywhere outside the $n$-th coordinate axis $A_n$, given by
$$\pi(a) = \|a\|\pi_{-1}(a) / \|\pi_{-1}(a)\|$$
where $\pi_{-1}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is just the projection onto the first $n-1$ coordinates $\pi_{-1}(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = (a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})$.

I don't think it can be continuously extended either since for example, when $n = 2$, the map takes spheres of radius $r$ (except north/south poles) to their equator but cannot be continuously extended.

I might still be able to make this work for my purposes, but just wanted to check if there were any continuous everywhere defined maps or if it is not possible.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}, x \mapsto \vert x \vert e_1$? This is clearly continuous and we have $\Vert a \Vert = \Vert b \Vert$ implies $\pi(a) = \Vert a \Vert e_1 = \Vert b \Vert e_1 = \pi(b)$. Or more drastic, $\pi(x) =0$, then your condition is also satisfied. I assume that you are missing some nice properties that you would like your map to preserve :)

Comment: If you don’t need it to be surjective, map to a one-dimensional ray emanating from the origin.

Comment: Alternatively, you can take $$\pi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}, (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_{n-2}, \Vert (x_{n-1}, x_n) \Vert). $$ We have $\Vert \pi(x) \Vert = \Vert x \Vert$ and $\pi$ is continuous (even lipschitz).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Oh shoot, yeah so I was essentially working with this map from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, shoulda just copied and pasted into $\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$

Comment: @CarsonJames It depends what you want to do. If that map is good enough for you, then sure. I just could not believe that this map does what you want :) It does not preserve much of the original structure.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost I wanted to see a surjective version, but was unable to come up with one.

Comment: @ronno How would you do that? I'd be happy to upvote an answer of yours, where you indicate how to construct that (I briefly tried, but was unable to do it).

Comment: @ronno Does your last comment imply that there cannot exist a surjective map at all? Sorry, if that is obvious from your comment, in first approximation I do not know any geometry/topology :) If that is the case, I'd love to see that as an answer, seems like a natural question to me, whether one can make our map surjective.

Comment: @CarsonJames By the way, there isn't an implication either way between being $O(n-1)$ equivariant and being norm preserving.

Comment: @ronno Thanks! I am a bit tired, can only see $D^{n-1} \rightarrow D^{n-2}$ right away. Will see tomorrow, whether I get the other maps together.

Comment: @ronno Thanks again.

Comment: @ronno Thanks for pointing that out. After looking at the wiki page for equivariance, it seems to be in the context of group actions. What I was trying to say was that if two points are equivalent mod an orthogonal transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then their images are equivalent mod an orthogonal transformation of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Is there a better word for this? In my notes I have been using the phrase $(\sim_X, \sim_Y)$- invariant where $\sim_X$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

Comment: I don't know terminology for this in general, but in this specific case "norm preserving" seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are a bunch of possible maps. For example all constant maps have the property, but those are typically not very useful.

Here are some more interesting examples, all with the slightly stronger property $\Vert \pi(x) \Vert = \Vert x \Vert$.

First the map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}, x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert e_1.$

Secondly, a map that is similar in spirit, but preserves a bit more structure $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}, (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_{n-2}, \Vert (x_{n-1}, x_n)\Vert)$.

Comment: oh that second one is pretty nice and both are good for me to play around with!

Comment: @CarsonJames Thank you. Please make sure to check out the beautiful example of ronno! His example is even surjective, which is much MUCH better than the what I have provided.

Answer (score 2):

If $f : S^{n-1} \to S^{n - 2}$ is any continuous map, then you can take $\pi(x) = f(x/||x||) ||x||$.

For $n > 2$ there are many such maps. For example, the composition of $S^{n - 1} \to D^{n-1}$ projecting to the first $(n-1)$ coordinates, $D^{n-1} \to D^{n-2}$ projecting to the first $(n-2)$ coordinates and $D^{n-2} \to S^{n-2}$ collapsing the boundary to a point produces a surjective map $S^{n-1} \to S^{n-2}$. For $n = 3$, let $r = ||(x, y, z)||$ and $t = x/r$ for $r \ne 0$. Then the above construction provides the explicit map $(x, y, z) \mapsto (r \cos(\pi t), r \sin(\pi t))$ (and $0 \mapsto 0$) where $\pi$ is the circumference of the unit circle, not the map.

Note that these examples are all norm preserving, ie $||\pi(x)|| = ||x||$. Restricting to such examples, $g(x) = \pi(x)/||\pi(x)|| = \pi(x)/||x||$ is a continuous map $\mathbb{R}^n - 0 \to S^{n-2}$, so for $n = 2$ has only $2$ choices (since $\mathbb{R}^n - 0$ is connected and $S^0 = \{\pm 1\}$ is $2$ discrete points). Since $\pi(x) = ||x|| g(x)$, it follows that for $n = 2$, $\pi$ has only two choices $x \mapsto ||x||$ and $x \mapsto -||x||$.

In fact, norm preserving maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ exactly correspond to continuous maps $\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times S^{n-1} \to S^{n-2}$ by the correspondence $\pi \leftrightarrow g$, where we have switched to polar coordinates, ie identified $\mathbb{R}^n - 0$ with $\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times S^{n-1}$.

This also shows that there cannot be a $\pi$ that is a retract, ie one that fixes $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ pointwise. Since for such a $\pi$, which would automatically be norm preserving, $g$ restricted to a hemisphere of $1 \times S^{n-1}$ would give a retract $D^{n-1} \to S^{n-2}$ of a disk to its boundary, which is well-known to not exist.

Comment: Just wanted to check, in your comments you have $S^{n-1} \rightarrow D^{n-1} \rightarrow D^{n-2} \rightarrow S^{n-2}$. Is $D^n$ the disk so that $D^1 \rightarrow S^1$ sends the interval $[-1, 1]$ to a single point in $\{-1, 1\}$?

Comment: @CarsonJames First, $S^1$ is a circle, not $\{\pm 1\} = S^0$. You could take any continuous map $D^1 \to S^1$ but in that comment I was trying to exhibit a surjective map, eg $t \mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$ wrapping the interval around the circle.